# Pylint nested pylintrc : Specify a configuration file

Tags: configuration, pylint, linter, pylintrc

### Goal

I want to use pylint without specifying the file path (just run `pylint` instead of `pylint --rcfile=linter/.pylintrc`), as I want to save all linter related files in a subfolder `linter/`.

I thought of adding a `.pylintrc` file at the root folder only a redirection to the actual config file `linter/.pylintrc`.

### Exploration

The option `rcfile` seems to be what I look for, it doesn't seems to import the settings from the sub-folder. What am I missing ?

Proposed `.pylintrc` file for redirection:

```
[MASTER]
# Specify a configuration file.
rcfile=subfolder/.pylintrc
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported in pylint see [this pull request](https://github.com/PyCQA/pylint/pull/7146)